# Issues with join / joinField / joinAttribute (undefined method)

Tags: join, join-table

I'm trying to join a category with an event.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$categories = $categoryModel->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $rootCategoryId))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', array('eq' => 1));
$categories->joinTable('catalogevent/event', 'entity_id=category_id');
```

The error I receive is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection::joinTable()

Any help is greatly appreciated. I get a similar error trying to use joinField and joinAttribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $rootCategoryId))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', array('eq' => 1));
$categoryModel->getSelect()->join('catalogevent/event', 'entity_id=category_id');
```